# Is it possible to wrap table rows responsively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

Is it possible to wrap a table row and its contents (tds) so that the table stays responsive? For example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
<td><!---content---></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Can those two rows of 5 become two rows of 4 and a row of 2 for some screen sizes, or three rows of 3 and one row of 1 for others, and so on?

Have tried floats and inline styling but the rows are always on the next line, and never flush next to one another so the td areas look seamless. **I have no access to the html of the table structure**, so I'm trying to target it with CSS or even Javascript/jQuery.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use a table - use div's. What you really want is a flexbox solution. None of the comments below suggest that.

Comment: You might find some ideas here: [Responsive Data Tables](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/)

Answer (score 1):

`table` elements are not designed to work the way you are asking. What you are asking is generally referred as **Responsive UI** and we have many ready-made solutions for that. I would strongly recommend Bootstrap library/framework for that purpose.

Bootstraps [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system will allow you to do what you are asking for. In case you rare interested in this approach, you can read about other options (other frameworks other than Bootstrap)as well [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/5-most-popular-frontend-frameworks-compared/).

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to the table. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

1) For your purposes you can use different types of table and show/hide some of them depending on screen size
Here is the solution for your case:

HTML:

```css
.table-xs {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-xs td {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .table-xs {
    display: table;
  }
}

/* === medium === */
.table-md {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-md td {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 541px) and (max-width: 720px) {
  .table-md {
    display: table;
  }
}

/* === large === */
.table-lg {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.table-lg td {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 721px) {
  .table-lg {
    display: table;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="table-lg">
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-md">
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">content</td>
    <td colspan="2">content</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table-xs">
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
    <td>content</td>
  </tr>  
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

2) You can use flexbox instead of table

Comment: I don't have access to the table. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Jerpl in that case, I don't think css only is going to do the trick

Comment: @Jerpl , ok. I added a new solution. Hope, it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this:

**CSS:**

```
.row {
    width: 100%;
}
.row > div {
    float: left;
}
.w25 {
    width: 25%;
}
.w33 {
    width: 33.333333%;
}
.w50 {
    width: 50%;
}
```

add more if you wish. After this css, you can simply call wherever you want.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="w50">1</div>
    <div class="w50">2</div>
</div>
```

In your case (5 cells) you could add `.w20 {width:20%;}` to the css, to use `<div class="w20></div>"` in the html.

---

There is only one minor disadvantage of using this method. Whenever you create tables, rows and cells, the cells are divided according to there content. But with my method, they will always be 20%, 50% or whatever.

Another alternative would be to use [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), but as you can see [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), not all browsers support this.

Comment: Difference here is you're using divs rather than using tables. The OP is asking about taking tabular data and letting CSS or JS completely disregard the defined table. I think.

Comment: edited this. I'm actually saying that this is a better solution, there is no way of doing what he wants using the default table structure

Comment: Snowmonkey is correct. The table is part of an ecommerce template which I have no access to to change. I want to target it with css or jquery as outlined in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an access to the table, you can re-render it according to the screen size.

You can try something like this:

```js
function renderTable() {
  var myTable = $('#myTable');
  var content_var = ["content01", "content02",
                "content03", "content04",
                "content05", "content06",
                "content07", "content08",
                "content09", "content10"];
  var html_lgTable = `
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[0]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[1]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[2]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[3]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[4]} </td> 
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[5]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[6]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[7]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[8]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[9]} </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`

  var html_mdTable = `
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[0]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[1]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[2]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[3]} </td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[4]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[5]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[6]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[7]} </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> ${content_var[8]} </td> 
      <td colspan="2"> ${content_var[9]} </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`

  var html_xsTable = `
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[0]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[1]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[2]} </td> 
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[3]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[4]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[5]} </td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> ${content_var[6]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[7]} </td> 
      <td> ${content_var[8]} </td> 
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"> ${content_var[9]} </td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`

  var windowW  = $(window).innerWidth();
  
  if (windowW < 500) {
    $('#myTable').html(html_xsTable);  
  }
  else if ((windowW > 500) && (windowW < 900)) {
    $('#myTable').html(html_mdTable);  
  }
  else $('#myTable').html(html_lgTable);
 }

$(document).ready(function() {
  renderTable();
  $(window).on("resize", function() {
       renderTable();
  })
});
```

```css
table {
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Of course, content_var array should be parsed from original table.